# Are Riemann-integrals supposed to have a finite value?

Tags: improper-integrals, riemann-integration

Specifically, I am dealing with a task that implies that constant functions are not Riemann-integrable over $[0, \infty[$ unless $f=0$. Is that true? I didn't manage to find anything on that particular statement.

Comment: Yes, if someone says $f$ is Riemann integrable, then I assume they mean the integral is finite.  In the case you mention, I would even say "the improper Riemann integral diverges".

Comment: Ordinarily the Riemann integral is only defined on intervals of finite length, so strictly speaking there is no such thing as being "Riemann-integrable over $[0,\infty)$".
Improper Riemann integrals are not the same as Riemann integrals.